# How to substitute a line containing regexp character with another line, with perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following code where I'm trying to substitute a certine line in a file with another line:

```
my %hFiles = (
    "file.v" => {
        "assign clk_2 = dft_clk_mux? clk : clk_2_r;" =>
            "clock_mux2 U_clock_mux2  .a(clk_2_r), .b(clk), .sel(dft_clk_mux), .z(clk_2));",
    },
);

foreach my $file ( keys %hFiles ) {
    open( my $input_file_handle, "<", $file ) or die "Can't open input file $file\n";
    open( my $output_file_handle, ">", "$result_dir/$file" ) or die "Can't create output file\n";
    my $output_file_string = `cat $file`;
    foreach my $line ( keys %{ $hFiles{$file} } ) {
        $output_file_string =~ s/$line)\n/$hFiles{$file}{$line}\n/g;
        print "$file\n$line\n$hFiles{$file}{$line}\n";
    }
    print $output_file_handle $output_file_string;
}
```

but the subsituation does not work. I think that this is because my line contains regexp characther so I've tried to replace it with:

```
my %hFiles = (
    "file.v" => {
        "assign clk_2 = dft_clk_mux\? clk : clk_2_r;" =>
            "clock_mux2 U_clock_mux2  \.a\(clk_2_r\), \.b\(clk\), .sel\(dft_clk_mux\), \.z\(clk_2\)\);",
    },
);
```

but it is still not working,
what can I do to succeed with replacing this line in a file?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis after `$line` and quote the special char:

```
$output_file_string =~ s/$line)\n/$hFiles{$file}{$line}\n/g;
```

becomes:

```
$output_file_string =~ s/\Q$line\E\n/$hFiles{$file}{$line}\n/g;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution worked!
another solution that worked were repalcong the line:

`"assign clk_2 = dft_clk_mux? clk : clk_2_r;" => "clock_mux2 U_clock_mux2  .a(clk_2_r), .b(clk), .sel(dft_clk_mux), .z(clk_2));", `

with:

`'assign clk_2 = dft_clk_mux? clk : clk_2_r;' => "clock_mux2 U_clock_mux2  .a(clk_2_r), .b(clk), .sel(dft_clk_mux), .z(clk_2));",`

i.e using  ' ' to describe the hash key and not  " "